# How to completely hide the seperator between windows?

Tags: vimrc, colorscheme, vim-windows, highlight

I managed to hide the background of the seperator between open windows by using:

```
hi VertSplit term=NONE cterm=NONE gui=NONE guifg=NONE guibg=NONE ctermfg=NONE ctermbg=NONE
```

However the `fillchars` still show up, and from my research it seems like its impossible to completely remove the `fillchars`. I figured there must be a way to make it `fillchars` invisible, but I cant seem to figure out how.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try hiding it using

```
set fillchars=vert:\ 
hi! VertSplit guifg=black guibg=black ctermfg=black ctermbg=black
```

Instead of `black` use color of your terminal or colorscheme background (not sure about various fancy terminals out there)

NOTE: `vert:\` the space at the end.

[image]

It also works with windows terminal (preview):

(you have to set fillchars, though)

[image]

Comment: These commands get rid of the background, but not the fillchars. I do have the background invisible already. I want to get rid of the `|` characters that appear when I do a vertical split.

Comment: The command makes fillchars the same color as background... and it works for non transparent terminals and gui. You probably have transparency set up in your terminal, haven't you?

Comment: For windows terminal with "useAcrylic" and transparency it doensn't work.

Comment: It still doesn't work with `useAcrylic` set to false. :( It also doesn't work in gVim. I've also been trying with `set fillchars=vert:\ `

Comment: Have you tried to set guifg and ctermfg colors to smth else then NONE? as in my example?

Comment: Bear in mind, you have to apply vertsplit highlighting AFTER your colorscheme. It wouldn't be enough to just specify it in your vimrc, you'll have to use autocommand as in @Matt answer.

Comment: Isn't this just a combination of the existing two answers?

Comment: @BLayer, yep. I will probably delete it if solution would be found

Comment: Thanks @MaximKim. The problem was that I had to set the hilight to `black` rather than `NONE`.

Answer (score 1):

> it seems like its impossible to completely remove the fillchars

You can't really remove it, but you can make it invisible:

```
" must be before setting your colorscheme
augroup nosplit | au!
    autocmd ColorScheme * hi VertSplit ctermfg=bg guifg=bg
augroup end
```

Comment: that doesn't work for me, I still see the | character on my vertical seperators

Comment: @mbl This one should do.

Comment: thank you, but still this doesn't have any effect for me. it seems like this script is trying to do the same thing that I posted in my original post, which works to an extent. It's just that the fillchar is still there, I see `|` characters on my vertically split windows still.

Answer (score 0):

While you have fixed `VertSplit` highlighting I don't see anywhere here the replacement of the actual vert `'fillchar'` value. We know removing it doesn't help as it will fall back to a default value but this seems to me to be a sufficient workaround:

```
:set fillchars=vert:\ ,..the rest..
```

(That's an escaped Space char.)

Comment: I tried `:set fillchars=vert:\ ` and it doesnt work. Does it actually work for you?

Comment: Indeed it does. I'm grasping at straws but try it with another value: `set fillchars=vert:\ ,fold:-` or `let &fillchars = 'vert: ,fold:-'`. Try refreshing screen with Ctrl-L...hmmm...thinking some more....try putting it in an autocmd in .vimrc. ... Will wait for your next update.

Comment: if I do a `set fillchars=vert:x` for example and then try `set fillchars=vert\ ` my vim goes back to showing `|` which seems to be my default fillchar

Comment: It's like the space is being ignored which drove some of my suggested workarounds.  The `let` version especially will make it impossible to cutoff the space. Let me know what happens with those and I'll think about it more.

Comment: What version of vim are you using and what system, btw?

Comment: im using vim `8.1.2102` on Windows10 inside the Windows terminal (I also tried inside of gVim)

Comment: I'm on Win10 and tried it with cygwin vim 8.1.1772 and gvim 8.1.0001...works both places....including when I run with `--clean`.

Comment: @BLayer try "useAcrylic" and transparency. Then it doesn't work.

Comment: @BLayer I stand corrected. It works.

Comment: @mbl So that's another person for which it works and I tried it on two other systems w/o problems. Worth going through my suggested workarounds, trying with `--clean`, etc.